# Latex- Lemma shows black rectangle at the end

Tags: theorems

I am having an issue with my latex document. When I use the lemma by using the below code it shows a small black rectangle at the end of every lemma.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\begin{document}

\section{ Analysis}

This section discusses essential proofs of some of the properties explained in the earlier,\\
\newtheorem{theorem}{\textbf{Lemma}}

\begin{theorem}
    Lemma statement 1
\end{theorem} 

\begin{IEEEproof}
    The body of the lemma.The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma.  The body of the lemma.The body of the lemma.The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma.   The body of the lemma.The body of the lemma.The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma.
\end{IEEEproof}

\newtheorem{theorem2}{\textbf{Lemma}}
\begin{theorem}
    Lemma statement 2
\end{theorem} 
\begin{IEEEproof}
    The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma. The body of the lemma.
\end{IEEEproof}

\end{document}
```

The above code shows the below output,

[image]

Comment: The box marks the end of the proof. So there is nothing wrong with it. You may be able to turn it off but if you are using this document class this may have the reason that you follow the conventions of a publisher, who might want to see these boxes.

Comment: The title of your posting is somewhat misleading, as it's the `proof` and not the `lemma` environment that inserts the QED symbols (here: black squares).

Comment: This is end of proof see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(typography)